# Using If as a question word

Tags: grammaticality, if-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the question mark misused in affirmative sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5619/is-the-question-mark-misused-in-affirmative-sentences)

Is it correct to use "if" in this way?

> I want to know if I can borrow your car?

Comment: We are currently trying to raise enough support for a website for beginner question: [English language learner's proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=9vM09OKxbaY8GxFV_g6lKw2). Please consider supporting this proposal.

Comment: @Matt,RegDwighт♦: Like Bill, I choose to interpret this question at face value - it asks about using the word "**if**", not about whether the question mark is "correct". And so far as I know there hasn't been a question about any possible difference between "**if**" and "**whether**" before on ELU. I therefore think this one was wrongly closed, and should be re-opened.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [When are “if” and “whether” equivalent?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/when-are-if-and-whether-equivalent) Though to me it doesn't look like this question here is asking about *if* vs. *whether*. In fact it is not clear to me what it is asking at all. I closed it as a duplicate as a courtesy to the OP; but in its current form it really is more of a NARQ.

Comment: Okay, thanks - I guess it's a moot point whether/if this question is clear or not, and what exactly it might be asking about. You've now found and posted a link there to an earlier question that *does* cover the same issue I see here, so let this closure stand.

Answer (score 1):

*Whether* and *if* are [normally synonymous](http://thesaurus.com/browse/whether?s=b) in contexts similar to the one provided in your sentence. Which you choose is a style preference in this case. I always choose *whether* for formal writing.

**[EDIT:]** Tim has a good point. The direct answer to your question, then, is: **Yes, it is correct to use "if" in this way**. And as SF. points out, neither of your sentences is a question: both are declarative statements that take no question mark.

Comment: Quite true, but not what OP is asking. *I want to know* shouldn't (but often does) take a question mark, whether it is followed by *whether*, *if*, or something else.

Comment: I too would normally use *whether* in formal contexts - but I really couldn't say **if** many others make this distinction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think not, but I have no proof, just prejudice.

Comment: Google Books - **formal**: ["I should like to know if"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+should+like+to+know+if%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):185,000 hits, ["I should like to know whether"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+should+like+to+know+whether%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):305,000. **Informal** ["I'd like to know if"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I'd+like+to+know+if%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):83,200 hits, ["I'd like to know whether"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I'd+like+to+know+whether%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) 21,300.

Comment: ...so basically it looks as if a *lot* of other people share our "prejudice"!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you for the uplifting numbers. I'm pleased to see that we're not alone!

Comment: RegDwight found an earlier dup that I'd missed, covering the *if/whether* distinction. There's [an answer there by Neil Coffey](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/15388/2637) (who I think is pretty clued-up about these things) where he says ***whether** tends to be preferred in formal use*. I've just upvoted his answer because the evidence strongly supports it. Other people on that earlier question seem to think it's relevant if/whether there are two or more "alternatives" being asked about, but frankly I think that's a load of cobblers. What say you?

Answer (score 0):

That's a statement, not a direct question, though it could be used in function of a question:

> I want to know if I can borrow your car.

This correctly states the intent and you could expect an answer, though it may sound rather harsh, a voice of annoyance/impatience.

> I'd like to know if I could borrow your car.

This is stating it in a more polite manner.
Note, how despite these functioning as questions/requests in the language, they are statements from grammar viewpoint so they end with a full stop.

Comment: Good observation. I missed that major point.