# On Interrogative Sentence

Tags: grammar, questions

Is it correct to make a sentence interrogative only with question mark (and tone) and without following essential grammatical rules?

For example, people usually say

> You are going to the stadium?

instead of

> Are you going to the stadium?

But, what about writing? I think doing so in writing may be problematic.
Is there any specific rule for that?

Comment: I'd say that doing so in writing would indeed be problematic. While talking, AmE seems to drop the `Are` frequently.

Comment: It's a different form of the usual interrogative, not one that is "without following essential grammatical rules" -- it has a subtly different implication from the regular interrogative structure. This may already have been dealt with here or on [ell.se] either directly or in a related issue.

Comment: @TusharRaj It's not just about dropping the *are* -- any statement can be turned into a question with a question-mark at the end in this way.

Comment: @Kris: That's why I said frequently, not always. I always felt there was a nuance involved. IMO, `You are going to the stadium?` puts  emphasis on `stadium`, and can be used when this emphasis is desired.

Comment: You're asking *us?* Excluding cited examples, your question text above includes two "normal" sequences *(Is it correct? Am I right?)* and one which would almost never be acceptable to any native speaker *Or **there is** a specific rule?* I wouldn't like to try to explain why @Kris isn't *quite* right to say ***any*** statement can be converted into a question by punctuation/intonation, but I feel it would require a *very* contrived delivery to achieve that with the last sentence in the question text above.

Comment: Hi! This is a pretty old discussion but I'm sure it'll help -http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5619/is-the-question-mark-misused-in-affirmative-sentences

Comment: Since @TusharRaj tells us that it's normal in AmE could I add that in British English it's normal to ask, "You're going to the pub?" or even "Going to the pub?"

Comment: See also the Nordquist article on [declarative questions](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/Declarative-Question-term.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if using it in writing it would have to be in a fairly informal context, e.g. dialogue between two characters, or in a short informal conversation, however in these instances I would either drop the *'are'* or contract the *'you are'* to *'you're'*

e.g.

> You're going to the stadium tomorrow?

Sounds perfectly natural to me

---

NB. Just had a thought, this would only really make sense if the topic had previously been mentioned, e.g. if you were *bringing up* the subject of your friend/colleague going to the stadium, then this would sound odd.

However, if asking for emphasis, or in exclamation, this would work.

### **Examples:**

```
You doing anything nice over the weekend?  
Yeah, thinking of playing a bit of football with some mates, want to come? 
*You're going* to the park?
```

**But:**

```
You doing anything nice over the weekend?  
Not sure yet
*Are you going to go* to the park?
```